# Passing credentials to dynamic inventory script

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I hope this is a question that has already been answered since I can't be the first one to wonder.

I have an Ansible dynamic inventory script and it connects to a server that needs a username and password.
I do not, for obvious reasons, want to hardcode it in my script.

I want a way to either ask user for it or somehow securely pass something from Ansible, perhaps a bit like ask-pass or similar.

If I design the script to ask for credentials then Ansible will never show the prompt for it and just hang.

So what options do I have for securely passing credentials to my dynamic inventory script?

Comment: For example, get it from a file.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. See [help/on-topic]. Try [SF].

Comment: why not use public-key cryptography?

Comment: public key would only work if the inventory script used ssh and this is not ssh related, it is application login.
getting the logins from a file, yes that would work but it is the solution i really want to avoid